# Jquery How to replace exact-match text

Tags: javascript, jquery

As titled, how to replace exact-match text to some text I want to. The button is function to replace the text when it clicked.

My expected result will be `Hello StackOverFlow, @L @Works @Lebron @lebron`

```js
function inputKeyUp(event, e) {

  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

$(document).on('click', '#replaceBtn', function(){
    let ori = $('#chatboxtextarea').text();
    let t1 = "@Works";
  let textToReplace = "@l";
  let afterReplace = ori.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+textToReplace+"\\b", "gi"), t1);
  //
  $('#chatboxtextarea').text(afterReplace);
});
```

```css
#chatboxtextarea{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="input chatboxtextarea" id="chatboxtextarea" name="chattxt" contenteditable  onkeyup="inputKeyUp(event,this);">Hello StackOverFlow, @L @l @Lebron @lebron</span>
<button id="replaceBtn">
Replace
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the regular expression.

---

First, it uses the `i` (case-insensitive) flag, so `@L` would be replaced as well (if the regular expression worked), producing this:

```
Hello StackOverFlow, @Works @Works @Lebron @lebron
```

...instead of this:

```
Hello StackOverFlow, @L @Works @Lebron @lebron
```

---

The second issue is related to the `\b` (word boundary) assertion. From [*Boundary-type assertions* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#boundary-type_assertions):

> `\b` matches a word boundary.
> This is the position where
> a word character is not followed or preceded by another word-character,
> such as between a letter and a space.

Word-characters (`\w`) match these characters: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. The `@` character is not a word-character.

So, because the `\b` in the `\b@l` part of the regex is *not* followed by a word-character (because the `@` character is not a word-character), it means that it must be *preceded* by a word-character. So this would be matched: `foo@l`, but this would not: `foo @l`.

One way to fix the issue is to use a [negative lookbehind assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions) to check that the `@` character is *not* preceded by a word boundary. Like this: `(?<!\b)@l`.

(If the value of `textToReplace` is different, e.g. if it starts with a word-character, you might need to use a different kind of fix. `"\\b" + textToReplace + "\\b"` might be ok.)

---

Here's your code with those two issues fixed (I modified only the line with the `afterReplace` variable):

```js
function inputKeyUp(event, e) {

  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

$(document).on('click', '#replaceBtn', function(){
    let ori = $('#chatboxtextarea').text();
    let t1 = "@Works";
  let textToReplace = "@l";
  let afterReplace = ori.replace(new RegExp("(?<!\\b)"+textToReplace+"\\b", "g"), t1);
  //
  $('#chatboxtextarea').text(afterReplace);
});
```

```css
#chatboxtextarea{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="input chatboxtextarea" id="chatboxtextarea" name="chattxt" contenteditable  onkeyup="inputKeyUp(event,this);">Hello StackOverFlow, @L @l @Lebron @lebron</span>
<button id="replaceBtn">
Replace
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. Well explained for the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#replaceBtn').on('click', function(){
    
  let ori = $('#chatboxtextarea').text();
  let t1 = "@Works";
  let afterReplace = ori.replace(/@l/g, t1);
  $('#chatboxtextarea').text(afterReplace);
});
```